# Python- converting to float using map()

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a list like the one given below, and want to convert the given integers to float, is there a way I can do it with map()?

```
my_list=[['Hello', 1 , 3],['Hi', 4 , 6]]
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried anything?

Comment: This question is a bit like: "I have a nail and a board. I would like the nail in the board. Can I do this using a shoe?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ugly, but yeah, it can be done:

```
my_list=[['Hello', 1 , 3],['Hi', 4 , 6]]

print(list(map(lambda lst: list(map(lambda x: float(x) if type(x) == int else x, lst)), my_list)))

# Output: [['Hello', 1.0, 3.0], ['Hi', 4.0, 6.0]]
```

**EDIT**

I personally prefer list comprehension in most cases as opposed to map/lambda, especially here where all the conversions to lists are annoying:

```
print([
    [float(x) if type(x) == int else x for x in lst]
    for lst in my_list
])
```

**EDIT 2**

And finally, an in-place solution that uses good old for loops:

```
for lst in my_list:
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if type(item) == int:
            lst[i] = float(item)

print(my_list)
```

Comment: This is so, so terrible I want to downvote it but there's no good reason. Technically, it's correct, and this time it's not the best kind of correct. :(

Comment: Thank you @smarx, I was looking for a method other than the loop! :)

Comment: There's an important difference between the map/comprehension and the loop -- the map creates a new list with the data copied and changed to float.  The loop, on the other hand, changes the data in place.  The difference is *CRUCIAL* if there are other references to the original list.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Agreed. That's why I made a point of calling out that it's an in-place solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `map`, you can increase readability by using it with previously defined functions. First make a function which converts an object to a float if possible, and leaves it alone if not:

```
def toFloat(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return x
```

Then you can map this across a list like:

```
def listToFloats(items):
    return list(map(toFloat,items))
```

And then map this last function across a list of lists:

```
def listsToFloats(lists):
    return list(map(listToFloats,lists))
```

For example:

```
>>> my_list=[['Hello', 1 , 3],['Hi', 4 , 6]]

>>> listsToFloats(my_list)
[['Hello', 1.0, 3.0], ['Hi', 4.0, 6.0]]
```