# python read file iand create a dictionary with real, integer and string

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, readfile

I would like to read a file with different characteristics and to transfer what I read to a dictionary. The problem is that, as far I have understood, all the data are read as string. This is a problem for me. I have indeed an array in my file.
In order to make myself clear I have set up the following example:

```
test_dic= {}

with open('test.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         c_line = line.split()
         print(c_line)
         
         if c_line[0] == 'aa':
             test_dic['aa']=c_line[1]
             
         if c_line[0] == 'bb':
             test_dic['bb']=c_line[1]
```

here how the file looks like:

```
aa    1
bb    1.5,13,1.4
```

I would to have test_dic['bb'] as it was an array and not a string.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: What is the pattern? Will `aa` only be an `int`? Will `bb` only be a list of `float`s? Or could any line contain any combination of `int`s, `float`s, or lists thereof?

Comment: This answer might be helpful [Python- converting to float using map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622177/python-converting-to-float-using-map)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         c_line = line.split(",") if ',' in line else line.split()
         print(c_line)
         
         if c_line[0] == 'aa':
             test_dic['aa']=''.join(line.split(" ")[1:]).split(",")
             
         if c_line[0] == 'bb':
             test_dic['bb']=''.join(line.split(" ")[1:]).split(",")
print(test_dic)
```